# How to find a property alias name in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, alias

I have a lot of stored procedures in my database. Now I want to find the stored procedure that has "movaghe" in the name of one of its aliases. Of course, I used the following command but it was not successful

```
SELECT
  ROUTINE_NAME,
  ROUTINE_DEFINITION
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%movaghe%' 
  AND ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'
```

Comment: Procedures don't have aliases, what do you mean? Do you mean an alias of a column selected in it, or do you mean perhaps a `SYNONYM`?

Comment: suppose part of my sp is : "select SUM(tr.MablaghGhest)  as SumMovaghe ........" and I want to find sp,s that include %movaghe%. So after search one of the sp,s that  is shown is above sp.

Comment: Is your database using a case sensitive collation?

Comment: What does "was not successful" mean? Did you get an error message? Wrong results? No results? Also I don't know if there is a very easy way to isolate the search against _just_ column aliases. A naive `LIKE` will also capture that string in table aliases, comments, string literals, etc.

Comment: No. Basically, I use the Persian language as Elias as the caption of the columns like this:  select SUM(tr.MablaghGhest) as 'جمع معوقات'. This is not the case in Persian.

Comment: `as 'جمع معوقات'` -> is not a proper way to define an alias. Use `as "جمع معوقات"` or `as [جمع معوقات]`. Not that that's the immediate problem. Likely you need to use `LIKE N'%movaghe%'` if the string you're _actually_ searching for is Unicode.

Comment: (And you should be doing that anyway, using `LIKE N'%something%'` instead of `LIKE '%something%'`, because the definitions are stored as `nvarchar`. Even if you aren't typing a Unicode literal, get into the habit so it doesn't bite you when you do.)

Comment: (If you're actually searching for `جمع معوقات` then that should be in your question - that would make the reason behind "not successful" more immediately obvious.)

Comment: @Stuckat1337, it's "fine" to use ' ' for alises, albeit perhaps it's better not to

Comment: @Stuckat1337 It's deprecated and will probably be removed at some point, it's also highly confusing.

Comment: Agreed, meant for @siggemannen?

Comment: A [`TSqlParser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.tsqlparser?view=sql-transactsql-161) will handle analyzing the procedure definition so that you can identify the aliases. Without a parser it is impractical to find the aliases.

Answer (score 4):

You could search the module definitions

```sql
SELECT
  p.name,
  m.definition
FROM sys.sql_modules m
JOIN sys.procedures p ON p.object_id = m.object_id
WHERE m.definition LIKE N'%movaghe%';
```

This is somewhat unreliable though, as it would include comments and object names.

Alternatively you can use `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object` but that only shows info for the first resultset in the procedure.

```sql
SELECT
  p.name,
  m.definition
FROM sys.sql_modules m
JOIN sys.procedures p ON p.object_id = m.object_id
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object(p.object_id, 0) r
    WHERE r.name LIKE N'%movaghe%'
);
```

Answer (score -2):

`ROUTINE_DEFINITION` column returns only 4000 symobls, if your procedure have more, it's will not return what you want. You can use this:

```
select o.name as ROUTINE_NAME,max(DF.ROUTINE_DEFINITION)  from sys.objects o 
  cross apply (select (select text+'' from sys.syscomments c where c.id = o.object_id for xml path('')) ROUTINE_DEFINITION) DF
where DF.ROUTINE_DEFINITION like '%movaghe%' and o.type_desc = 'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE'
group by o.name
```

Comment: Anyway thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: `sys.sql_modules` is what you are looking for, as well as `sys.procedures`. The `sys.syscomments` view is ancient and unreliable.

Comment: syscomments is split per 4000 chars, so if you're unlucky, the name will be split on multiple rows thus you won't get a match